# What makes C# "component oriented"?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean when you say C# is component oriented language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234283/what-does-it-mean-when-you-say-c-is-component-oriented-language)

What characteristics make the C# language a component-oriented (whatever that means) programming language. Weren't the classical (pun intended) "object oriented" label enough for conveying its core philosophy ??

Comment: None of the responses to the previous question is actually an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was already asked...

[What does it mean when you say C# is component oriented language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234283/what-does-it-mean-when-you-say-c-is-component-oriented-language)

Enjoy.

Comment: But not really answered.